# Updating Yocto Layer IMX8 Solidrun

Tags: linux, yocto, imx8

I want to know how I could upgrade a yocto layer (in this case IMX8-solidrun layer, hardknott). They aren't going to update this layer, but I would like to build a last version Yocto image, but this layer is completely obsolete.

Could I upgrade the layer manually? What are the steps to do it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Update the LAYERSERIES_COMPAT option in layer.conf to desired release and just try to match the recipes version to latest releases also while compiling the image as well you will get to know minimum required versions of packages while dependencies are building So update the versions accordingly